# How to remove/hide elements from the admin menu?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I would like to hide **Pages** and **Comments** from the editor.

I tried to override them with my custom types' *menu_position* but it doesn't work in **WordPress 3.7.1** any more.

I found another way: removing the entries from **admin menu** by altering the global *$menu* variable on *menu_order* **filter**. Unfortunately it produces errors in *menu.php*: *array_flip()* gets passed a *null*.

I'm guessing that WordPress assumes that default values are still there.

Is there some way of filtering the menu entries **when** they are **rendered**?
Even better: is there a way of setting the **default post** types *public* option to **false**?

```
class RemoveAdminMenuItems {

/**
 * List of values used for key identification
 * 
 * @var array
 */
public $remove_keys = array();

/**
 * List of values used for key identification. Identified keys will be removed.
 * 
 * @param array $remove_keys
 */
public function __construct($remove_keys)
{

    $this->remove_keys = $remove_keys;

    add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', '__return_true' );
    add_filter( 'menu_order', array($this, 'reconstruct_menu'));

}

/**
 * Method modifies the admin menu before it gets rendered.
 * 
 * @global array $menu
 */
public function reconstruct_menu() {

    global $menu;

    foreach ($menu as $menu_key => $menu_value) {
        foreach ($this->remove_keys as $remove_key) {
            $key = array_search($remove_key, $menu_value);
            if ($key) {
                unset($menu[$menu_key]);
            }        
        }
    }

}

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *end user* here?

Comment: Obviously I meant the editor. :) Thx.

Comment: Well, it wasn't *obvious*; else I wouldn't have asked. You could have meant users of a given user role - which could potentially lead to a viable solution, through modifying user capabilities.

Comment: You are right. The answer was pretty _obvious_: User Capabilities. I prefer doing it by the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to hide the menu items, you can do it like shown below. Don't forget about the entries inside the admin bar.

**Code:**

```
//hide in admin menu
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse121406_hide_pages_comments_m' );
function wpse121406_hide_pages_comments_m() {
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
}

//hide in admin bar
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpse121406_hide_pages_comments_b' );
function wpse121406_hide_pages_comments_b() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-page');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');
}
```

**But** you have to keep in mind that *this doesn't disable/restrict the functionality*. The edit pages and the comments page can still be reached by typing in the address into the location bar. If you want to restrict access by user type you have to go with [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

---

**Update:**

Regarding your second question, on how to alter the built in post types properties. You can achieve this by going at it like shown below. You can use the `registered_post_type` or the `init` hook and can either use [`get_post_type_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object) or the global `$wp_post_types`.

**Code:**

```
add_action('init','wpse121406_alter_post_type_object');
function wpse121406_alter_post_type_object() {
  $object = get_post_type_object('page');
  $object->public = false;
}
```